# Union in one source file not able to access same values as another source file?

Tags: c, unions

#### `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "comp.h"

union memory mem1;

int main() {
    int choice;
    unsigned int addlo, addhi;
    unsigned short data;
    int k;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please Select a Command\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("1. Load S-Record\n");
        printf("2. Read Memory\n");
        if(1 != scanf("%d", &choice) == 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read command.\n");
            break;
        }
        else if(choice == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(choice == 1)
        {
            loader();
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            for(k = 1; k<= 10; k++)
            {
                printf("k: %x mem: %x\n", k, mem1.byte[k]);
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### `comp.h`

```
void loader(void);
union memory{
    unsigned char byte[0x10000];
    unsigned short word[0x8000];
};
```

#### `loader.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "comp.h"

union memory mem;

void loader (void){
    
    int i;
    mem.byte[0] = 0xA1;
    mem.byte[1] = 0xA2;
    for(i = 0; i<= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %x mem: %x\n", i, mem.byte[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Please Select a Command
0. Exit
1. Load S-Record
2. Read Memory
1
i: 0 mem: a1
i: 1 mem: a2
i: 2 mem: 0
i: 3 mem: 0
i: 4 mem: 0
i: 5 mem: 0
i: 6 mem: 0
i: 7 mem: 0
i: 8 mem: 0
i: 9 mem: 0
i: a mem: 0
Please Select a Command
0. Exit
1. Load S-Record
2. Read Memory
2
k: 1 mem: 0
k: 2 mem: 0
k: 3 mem: 0
k: 4 mem: 0
k: 5 mem: 0
k: 6 mem: 0
k: 7 mem: 0
k: 8 mem: 0
k: 9 mem: 0
k: a mem: 0
Please Select a Command
0. Exit
1. Load S-Record
2. Read Memory
```

So my main issue as you can see is that I am working with a project file. Two source files and one header where my union is declared. I want both source files to be able to access my union as I am writing data into it. When I call my loader to load the data it prints showing that the union contains the values I load in it. When I then try to print the same data in my main it is not there? Is this due to my union not being a global, or is it due to the data not being saved from the loader (1) selection to the Read memory (2) selection? Any help would be great!

Comment: `mem` and `mem1` are different variables. Why would you think they would automatically have the same values? Change the `main` one to be `extern union memory mem;`. Better still, avoid using global variables - pass in a pointer to the union to the `loader` function.

Answer (score 0):

As kaylum commented, `mem1` and `mem` are different variables pointing at different memory so they will have different values.

You could use a single global, but [global variables should be avoided](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Why-should-we-avoid-using-global-variables-in-C-Cplusplus). Instead, don't declare `mem` in loader.c; have `loader` accept a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void loader (union memory *mem){
    mem->byte[0] = 0xA1;
    mem->byte[1] = 0xA2;

    for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %x mem: %x\n", i, mem->byte[i]);
    }
}
```

And then pass a pointer to `mem1` in.

```
        else if(choice == 1)
        {
            loader(&mem1);
        }
```

---

Also this is weird: `if(1 != scanf("%d", &choice) == 1)`. I'm guessing it should be `if(1 != scanf("%d", &choice))`, or to match the style everywhere else in the code, `if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)`